# Format a float to pad with leading spaces

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, number-formatting

I can get the result I want with leading zeros, but it does not work with spaces.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%05.2f", 2.1]; // 02.10
```

However, the following does not work:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"% 5.2f", 2.1]; // 2.10
```

Nor does this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%5.2f", 2.1]; // 2.10
```

Comment: put the space before the modulus, not after the modulus.

Comment: how can a number contain leading spaces?

Comment: how do you know it hasn't worked? try "[% 5.2f]" to see if there are any leading spaces, there should be 4, if it is not working, maybe objective c library did not implement it?

Comment: you could try setting the field width, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%*.2f", 5, 2.1]

Comment: @CodaFi - I don't think you understood my question. I want to PAD the float value to a minimum width with SPACES not just put a space before the number.

Comment: @AKV - If you took a sec to read the examples posted you would know I am asking about formatting to a string.

Comment: @izk: do you want to pad all values with some fixed spaces or characters?

Comment: @AKV pad to a specific widht with spaces.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried this and it wored:

```
printf("%s\n", [[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"% 5.2f\n", 2.1 ] UTF8String ] ) ;
```

which gives

```
 2.10
```

which is correct... maybe the problem lies elsewhere?

*EDIT*

If you aren't using a fixed width font, you can insert tab characters instead with `\t`

Answer (score 1):

I think my original solution works as does that suggested by @ColWhi and @nielsbot... I think the issue is the font (Helvetica) has narrower spaces than characters...